# How to Pass Multiple Input Variables To A Method Call

Tags: python-3.x, iteration

I am trying to write some code to accept three variables user input and to do different things if the user only enters one, two or all three, using if statements. 
I cannot seem to get it right, and I do not seem to be passing the third variable correctly to the method that needs it. 
I wonder if someone could please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
 def test_codes(self):
    codestring = input("Enter a functioning codestring: ")
    wildcard = input("Enter the wildcard string for the codestring, or press enter to ignore: ")
    phone_num = input("Enter the phone_num phone number of your choice, or press enter to ignore: ")
    if codestring:
        self.testscode.makecall(codestring)
    if codestring and wildcard:
        phone_num =  "1234457890"
        self.testscode.makecall(codestring, wildcard, phone_num)
    if codestring and wildcard and phone_num:
           if phone_num:
                self.testscode.makecall(codestring, wildcard, phone_num)
           else:
                phone_num = "1234457890"
                self.testscode.makecall(codestring, wildcard, phone_num)
```

Comment: Can you please show us what output you expected and which you received? The code of `makecall()` would also be helpful.

Comment: Added some more details, @xsquared